# Ajax request returns 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)

Tags: jquery

I want to make an request from

```
webapp.mysite.net
```

to

```
mysite.net/request.php?param=...
```

The response is plain text. But I keep getting an error

[image]

The `async` param must be set to `false`.

I assume my request is called `cross-domain request`. So I setup a [simple php proxy](https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy/raw/master/ba-simple-proxy.php) to solve the problem, but this does not work for me. It gives me an emtpy response.

I try to solve this problem for about two days now but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: well everything I do I have in the jsFiddle, no jsonp, the url returns plaint text

Comment: You can't test this on jsFiddle as they don't have any proxy. Anyway I'll go by debugging and fixing the PHP code as this is the correct approach - what happens when you browse directly to the PHP proxy giving the desired URL?

Comment: Just a thought..... did you send such request to the PHP? `ba-simple-proxy.php?url=http://example.com/` calling it directly will indeed generate empty response, you must specify what URL you want to read.

Comment: @Art so the PHP proxy works just fine, the `6.8320` can be parsed from the response.

Comment: I have got an idea but I don't think you are going to like it. `echo file_get_contents();`  in `test.php` and send request to it. This works but not according to your question. I am also looking for same sorta thing. So if found anything or recommendation then alert me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether the smsflatrate.net supports JSONP but this is what you'd have to use to get cross domain JSON request. But if I were you I probably wouldn't post your appkey and in public like you just did.

To use a proxy you have to have it on the same domain as you serve your HTML from, or use JSONP.

Also, why do you use async: false with callbacks? The only effect will be completely blocking the browser while the request takes place. And JSONP or any cross-domain requests can only be asynchronous.

Answer (score 5):

Ok,

I had a similar problem when making ajax Requests to the same domain and same level.

Don't make ajax request to

http://www.site.com

use

http://site.com

No idea why this is triggering this error, maybe somebody else will have this problem.